# Decided: How in Python 3 encode file, for open this file with PHP zlib_decode function?

Tags: python, php

**EDIT:**
I found a fix, must use wb+ option for save binary files and dont use str()

Code in PHP that i cant change:

```
file_get_contents('data.pak');
$s_st = unserialize(zlib_decode($s_st));
```

I try this Python code:

```
import zlib
from phpserialize import serialize

file = zlib.compress(serialize(data), 9)

with open('data.pak', 'w+') as f_out:
    f_out.write(str(file))
    f_out.close()
```

But PHP cant open this file.
I also install PHP to check what file create zlib_encode (zlib_encode(serialize($data),15)) with same data, and these files are different.

Python file starts from:

b'\xa5\xbd\xcb\xb2,)\xaeh\xdb\x8e\xf3\x19\xd5O3\xe7\rY_s\x9b\xbb\xbd\x9b\xd7\xce\xbf\

Looks like file content in bytes

PHP file starts from:

њҐќ[Ом(і¦ЇіҐћDЯ—dО°{X=©‰ њ пЗRХ_»цЄ§Н1€гяыw]!‡ящ?ЖеЏsсъ„l?—фЧяю_ќuз!Фz¤СЙ`\ши

So my question is: How create file in Python, that I can then open in PHP, using code at the beginning.

Comment: maybe use level 0 instead of 9?

Comment: @JoranBeasley  nope, same problem "PHP Warning:  zlib_decode(): data error in"

Comment: Don't use the str() function. Save the binary content.

Comment: @Olivier Got error TypeError('write() argument must be str, not bytes')

Comment: Just find the correct Python API to write binary content to a file (I'm not a Python developer, sorry).

Comment: @Olivier This is what Python does, and it saves in binary mode, as you can see file saved in Python starts from "b'\xa5\xbd\xcb\xb2,)\xaeh\xdb\x8e\xf3\x19\xd5O3\xe7\rY_s\x9b\xbb\xbd\x9b\xd7\xce\xbf\" so its binary file

Comment: This is an ASCII representation of binary content, not raw binary content.

Comment: @Oliver you was right i should use wb+ to save binary content and dont use str()